# xml/parse: how to convert the string in file into lower case before parse?

Tags: clojure

To parse a xml file in clojure we could use

```
 (clojure.xml/parse file)
```

But the xml has both upper case and lower case, and I'd like to convert all the strings into lower case before parse. One solution is to create temp file based on the file, and that temp will have the lower case string. But is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this?

```
(-> file
    slurp
    clojure.string/lower-case
    clojure.data.xml/parse-str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can read the file and save it in a String, but you can't done that without parse it twice, if you don't want to modify your functions to parse the file. That's what I should do, if I were you.